# Crear Objeto Javascript con Plantillas de Cadenas de texto

Tags: javascript, objeto, evaluación

Quería saber si puedo definir un objeto en javascript con las plantillas de cadenas de texto (``) y si es así, cómo sería la sintaxis correcta.
Me refiero a algo del estilo de:

```
var mi_objeto = `{prop: 1, atr: 2}`;
```

Comment: ¿Con qué objetivo? ¿Qué uso práctico le darías?

Comment: preguntas por backticks (``)?

Comment: @Mariano el objetivo es simplemente crear el objeto, como lo podría hacer de esta forma: `var mi_objeto = {prop : 1, atr : 2};` Es sólo una duda, ya que sería más cómodo crear objetos con un PEG.

Comment: @Héctor sí, eso mismo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La manera de conseguirlo es usando `eval` para evaluar la expresión entre ``. Las plantillas de cadena de texto devuelven una cadena de texto, y esa cadena la pasas como argumento a `eval`:

```js
var mi_objeto = eval(`{prop: 1, atr: 2}`);
```

Aunque parezca que debe funcionar, esto da un error de sintaxis (no sé la razón de ello). La manera de solucionarlo es envolver el objeto entre paréntesis para que la evaluación se realice correctamente:

```js
var mi_objeto = eval(`({prop: 1, atr: 2})`);

console.log(mi_objeto);
```

Si la cadena con el objeto en su interior la tienes guardado en una variable, no tienes más que concatenar los paréntesis:

```js
var objeto_cadena = `{prop: 1, atr: 2}`;
var mi_objeto = eval("("+objeto_cadena+")");

console.log(mi_objeto);
```

---

*PD: La información ha sido obtenida de esta entrada de SO en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010775/javascript-eval-and-object-evaluation*

Comment: Genial, esa era la respuesta que estaba buscando. Aunque estaría bien que si alguien sabe el motivo de error del primer código lo explicase.

Comment: Aquí la respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83462/error-sintaxis-en-eval-javascript/83466#83466