# Error Sintaxis en eval Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, objeto, evaluación

Al intentar pasar de un objeto definido en `backticks`:

```
var mi_objeto = `{propiedad1: 'a', propiedad2: 'b'}`;
```

A un objeto real mediante el método `eval`:

```
var objeto_real = eval(mi_objeto);
```

Me da un error de sintaxis, que se arregla si añado paréntesis a la definición de `mi_objeto`:

```
var objeto_real = eval("(" + mi_objeto + ")");
```

¿A qué se debe el error de sintaxis cuando hago el `eval` sin los paréntesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problema:**

Por qué si intento evaluar un literal de un objeto dentro de una cadena usando `eval()` da un error (*caso 1*), mientras que si el mismo literal del objeto se encierra entre paréntesis no da ningún problema (*caso 2*):

*Caso 1:*

```js
var mi_objeto = eval(`{propiedad1: 'a', propiedad2: 'b'}`);
console.log(typeof mi_objeto);
console.log(mi_objeto);
```

*Caso 2:*

```js
var mi_objeto = eval(`({propiedad1: 'a', propiedad2: 'b'})`);
console.log(typeof mi_objeto);
console.log(mi_objeto);
```

**Explicación:**

Si una apertura de corchete no se encuentra en un *contexto de expresión* (como una asignación, por ejemplo), JS lo considera como apertura de un bloque de código. Como las evaluaciones realizadas por `eval()` no se consideran en un *contexto de expresión*, el literal del objeto pasado por argumento, al empezar por `{`, es evaluado como creación de un bloque de código que contiene cadenas y `:`, dando como resultado un error de sintaxis.

Para solucionarlo, se debe incluir entre paréntesis la definición del literal objeto, ya que los paréntesis pueden solo evaluar expresiones, generando un *contexto de expresión* para la definición del literal del objeto que empieza por `{`. De esta manera, dentro de los paréntesis, el `{` ya no se considera como iniciación de un bloque de código, sino como creación de un objeto.

---

*La información ha sido obtenida de esta entrada de SO en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360356/why-the-open-quote-and-bracket-for-eval-jsonstring-when-parsing-json*

Comment: Exactamente es eso, modifico la respuesta correcta. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

El error se debe a que le estas pasando a la funcion eval el string `"{propiedad1: 'a', propiedad2: 'b'}"`. Esto se debe a conviertes implicitamente a string al sumar la cadena "(" con el objeto `mi_objeto`. Otra forma de hacerlo es esta:

```js
var mi_objeto = `{propiedad1: 'a', propiedad2: 'b'}`;
var objeto_real = eval('mi_objeto');
console.log(objeto_real);
```

Ten en cuenta que la funcion `eval` recibe como parametro un string. Y al recibir un objeto lo intenta convertir a string.  Tu expresion era equivalente a `eval("{propiedad1: 'a', propiedad2: 'b'}")`, lo que da claramente un error de sintaxix.
[Clickea aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) para informarte mas acerca de la funcion `eval`.

Sobre lo que me comentas, ya eso es mas bien de lo complicado que es javascript, no tanto como con lo de eval. Por ejemplo esto no da error:

```js
({propiedad1: 'a', propiedad2: 'b'})
```

Mientras que esto si:

```js
{propiedad1: 'a', propiedad2: 'b'}
```

Eval solo intenta encontrar una declaracion o una variable o algo en el string que le pasas.

Comment: Claro, la duda venía de una respuesta que me mandó un compañero en una pregunta anterior (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83331/crear-objeto-javascript-con-plantillas-de-cadenas-de-texto), y no me había dado cuenta. Gracias

Comment: Ayudadme, porque la verdad es que sigo sin entenderlo. *Sin utilizar variable intermedia*: si claramente es erróneo `eval("{propiedad1: 'a', propiedad2: 'b'}")`, ¿por qué no es erróneo `eval("({propiedad1: 'a', propiedad2: 'b'})")`?. *Usando variable itermedia*: si claramente es erróneo `obj = "{propiedad1: 'a', propiedad2: 'b'}"; eval(obj)`, ¿por qué no es erróneo `obj = "({propiedad1: 'a', propiedad2: 'b'})"; eval(obj)`?.

Comment: Edite mi pregunta por lo que me comentas, espero entiendas.

Comment: @Theia La verdad es que no estoy de acuerdo con tu respuesta. Lo primero, poner dentro de una cadena el nombre de la variable donde se guarda como cadena la definición del objeto, no soluciona el problema; porque al evaluarse con `eval()` dicha cadena con el nombre de la variable no da como resultado un objeto, sino una cadena con la definición del objeto, que no es lo mismo.
Y lo segundo, si te vas al intérprete de JS del navegador, y escribes directamente el objeto, te lo evalúa correctamente sin paréntesis y sin necesidad de incluirlo en una cadena.

Comment: @Theia En el primer código que has escrito, añade `console.log(typeof objeto_real)`, y verás que muestra `string` y no `object`. Es decir, no obtienes con `eval()` el objeto real, sino una cadena con la definición del objeto.
Sé que la manera de que evalúe correctamente el objeto usando `eval()` es incluir la definición entre paréntesis, pero sigo sin saber por qué. De hecho, el intérprete de JS embebido en los comentarios debe usar algo parecido porque actúa de manera similar.

Comment: @IbrahimHernándezJorge Creo que esta respuesta no es correcta, lo explico en mis dos comentarios anteriores.